# how to check a div is hidden or visible in angular 4?

Tags: angular

i have declared "sample" variable as false in a component and assigned *ngIf Condition check in HTML.

obviously it hides the div

but here i want to know check whether that div is hidden or visible?

Thanks in Advance

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBB1B.png)

Comment: `but here i want to know whether that div is hidden or visible?` <= What do you mean by that? Where do you want to know this? Why can't you also check the field/variable being checked in *ngIf ?

Comment: Where is "here"?  Just check the same `sample` variable wherever you need to know if it's visible.

Comment: I want to check whether that div is hidden or visible how can I do that?

Comment: It does not hide the div, it *removes it from the DOM.*

Comment: Also, please paste code as text into questions directly, not as images: there is a code formatting button for that in the editor. :)

Comment: How can I hide a div and check whether it is hidden or visible how it can be possible in angular?

Comment: If you can't just look at the state of the `sample` variable, then I'm not sure what you're asking. Post the code where you want to check it (as text, not as an image) and hopefully that will clarify it more.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply `[hidden]="myBooleanVariable"`, `*ngIf` prevents the element from being rendered in the `DOM` if `false`
The `HTML-Element` should now be rendered with `display:hidden`

Answer (score 1):

The Angular `ngIf` directive inserts or removes an element based on a `truthy/falsy` condition.

Which means if you use `*ngIf*` the div will not be available in the DOM. Using `[hidden]="yourCondition"` will keep the div/element in the DOM but make it's display hidden to the user.

so if `sample` is false and you are using `*ngIf` the div will not be present in DOM and hence not visible. but if using `[hidden]="sample"`, and if sample is true, it will hide the div but it will be available in DOM.